# Interaction with windows GUI

Tags: c++, asp.net, c, windows, user-interface

I want to create an application when user starts it, it records what user clicked on GUI in a file.
I don't know how and where to start. which language to use for this ?

Comment: No need for an application to do this. Windows has it built in. You can set an SACL to log when a particular executable is run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Most GUI depends on which platform you use.(i.e. in windows, you can use 
windows api.In linux, you can use QT. In java, use swing.)
But logic stuff depends on which language you use. Like manipulate numbers,
strings.
In sum, if you want to make it quickly, you can study using python.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Platform you can use  MFC(Microsoft Foundation Class)

[Here is a good tutorial](http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/index.html) for getting started with MFC

If you are expecting a free development environment, Qt would be a better choice.
[Qt Windows Support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-support.html)